# What's the meaning of "No Agencies Please"?

Tags: meaning

I often see the following messages:

> Restrictions:
>
> 1. Telecommuting is OK
> 2. No Agencies Please

I don't know the meaning of *No Agencies Please*.

I guess it means there is no realistic office space for you. Am I right?

Comment: @PeterMortensen the comma before “please” is entirely optional; it’s common in Europe but less common in the US.

Comment: This is strictly about the definition of the word "agency", which you should quite easily be able to decipher with a Google search or two. Given that this is presumably on a job ad, you might Google something like "job agency definition" or "work agency definition", which should lead you to the answer straight away.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No employment agencies offering to place someone in the position.

They want to be directly contacted by applicants.

Comment: An equivalent phrase that's also seen is "principals only".

Comment: @CCTO Unless you're applying to be a teacher ;p